# Adding class to li after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a nav bar with links that are loaded from a database by a foreach loop, the nav bar is static so only the content in changing. I want to add an 'Active' class to the link when the page is loaded an active.

I've tried to simply add class when an `li` element is clicked, but the class disappears when the page is reloading.

Here is my HTML (it's rendered by PHP foreach loop so it's not hard coded as it looks)

```
<div class="sidebar-menu">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li class="icon_links">
      <a href="/home" class="links">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="title">Dashboard</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon_links">
      <a href="/messaging" class="links">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="title">Messaging</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selector = '.sidebar-nav li';
  $(selector).on('click', function() {
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: Of course, `li` will not have the `active` class while reloading. On click only it will add class (As per your code.). Do you want to keep highlight the same li, on reload of the page?

Comment: You would need to select it on page load. It is a common question on how to do it, hopefully someone can find a dupe.

Comment: Initially you have to active class to current li using PHP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
    var selector = '.sidebar-nav li';
    var url = window.location.href;
    var target = url.split('/');
     $(selector).each(function(){
        if($(this).find('a').attr('href')===('/'+target[target.length-1])){
          $(selector).removeClass('active');
          $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('active');
        }
     });
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: :)) No problem. Happy coding!

Comment: I needed to make a change. `===('/'+target[target.length-1])` to `===(target[target.length-1])`. Only

Comment: @Carlos, Yes it depends upon how you have href in your code. For asked question it was like `href="/messaging"` so i added `/` if you have href without any `/` then you dont need to add it.

Comment: In my case first the code is running, removing/adding the "active" class and then reloading, in the result of which again all default settings are back.

Answer (score 6):

Function below add class active to all links that lead to current page you are on.

```
$(function(){
       $("a").each(function(){
               if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname){
                       $(this).addClass("active");
               }
       });
});
```

Source https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/highlight-all-links-to-current-page/

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood from you context you try to dynamicaly set a class to a dom element while reloading your page?

The thing is that while using direct links / form (with normal behaviour) you will reload the current page (or moving to a new one) which unset your currents modification and get your page back as it was in the first place.

I do think you should either:
use an `iframe` inside your page that would be the only part of your page that is reloaded. 
Or using `ajax`, you replace the section containing your current page's content with the new page's content

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
     $(selector).toggleClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');

Answer (score 0):

> I use the simple way

```
<script>
        var header = document.getElementById("ActiveId");
        var btn = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
        for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
            btn[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
                current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
                this.className += " active";
            });
        }
    </script>
```

**I hope it's help someone**

Answer (score 0):

> // add this code direct in your js file in line : 0

```
var url = window.location.href;
var tg = url.split('/');

    jQuery('.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link').each(function(){

        url_this = jQuery(this).attr("href");
        var ts = url_this.split('/');


            if(decodeURIComponent(tg[tg.length -2]) === decodeURIComponent(ts[ts.length -1]) ){
                jQuery(this).addClass('active');
                return false;
            }else{
                if(decodeURIComponent(tg[tg.length -2]) === decodeURIComponent(ts[ts.length -2]) ){
                    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
                    return false;
                }
            }


    });
```